# Removing Quotes From String

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql

I am passing a parameter to a dynamic sql string and have the parameter properly encompassed in `'` marks to work in my dynamic sql.  However, now I am needing to use the value in a diff location in my code, and want to remove all the `'` marks.  I tried the `Replace()` function, but I must be using incorrect syntax as it still leaves the string with single quotes on each side.  Take the sample DDL Below

```
DECLARE @Param1 nvarchar(500) = N'''Blue Bell Ice Cream''';
PRINT REPLACE(@Param1, '''''', '')
```

Prints this

> 'Blue Bell Ice Cream'

My desired result to be returned is

> Blue Bell Ice Cream

How should I write the `REPLACE()` function in order to remove all single quotes?

Comment: have you tried with: `REPLACE(@Param1, '''', '')` or `REPLACE(@Param1, '\'', '')`

Comment: @mcNets - why does your example of '''' work, but mine with '''''' does not and the string has 6 single quotes surrounding it?  And the second example produces an error of Incorrect syntax near '\', ')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using 6 quotes, this is not correct, you are trying to replace every single quote ', then use only a double quote '' to indicate the string pattern.

If you use '''' four quotes you are really searching for a double ''

```
REPLACE(@Param1, '''', '')
```